# How to create image with shapes and radius dynamically?

Tags: php, image, gd

I am working on product design creation using php image gd library. User can select shape and can set radius value for top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right and according to user selection image will create of that shape and radius.I am able to set radius and shape of top left corner of image but not getting that how i will set the top right, bottom left and bottom right radius according to user selection.

This is my code:

```
<form method="post" name="myform">

<input type="text" value="20" name="w" />

<input type="text" value="20" name="l" />

<div>
<label>Left Top </label>
<select name="shape1">
    <option value="round">round</option>
    <option value="square">square</option>

</select>
<label>Radius</label>
<select name="valbr1">
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

</div>


<div>
<label>Right Top </label>
<select name="shape2">
    <option value="round">round</option>
    <option value="square">square</option>

</select>
<label>Radius</label>
<select name="valbr2">
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

</div>


<div>
<label>Left Bottom </label>
<select name="shape3">
    <option value="round">round</option>
    <option value="square">square</option>

</select>
<label>Radius</label>
<select name="valbr3">
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

</div>

<div>
<label>Right Bottom </label>
<select name="shape4">
    <option value="round">round</option>
    <option value="square">square</option>

</select>
<label>Radius</label>
<select name="valbr4">
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$w = $_POST['w'];
$l = $_POST['l'];

$corner_shape[1] = $_POST['shape1'];
$corner_shape[2] = $_POST['shape2'];
$corner_shape[3] = $_POST['shape3'];
$corner_shape[4] = $_POST['shape4'];
$corner_val[1] = $_POST['valbr1'];
$corner_val[2] = $_POST['valbr2'];
$corner_val[3] = $_POST['valbr3'];
$corner_val[4] = $_POST['valbr4'];

$canvas_inner_width= $w*4;
$canvas_inner_height= $l*4;
$canvas_width=$canvas_inner_width+75;
$canvas_height=$canvas_inner_height+75;
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($canvas_width, $canvas_height);

function centertext($width ,$height,$w)
{
    $width = $width;
    $height = $height;

     $im = ImageCreate($width, $height);
     $bg = ImageColorAllocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
     $border = ImageColorAllocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
     ImageRectangle($im, 0, 0, $width - 1, $height - 1, $border);
     $text = $w;

        $textcolor = ImageColorAllocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
     // Font Size
        $font = 3;
         $font_width = ImageFontWidth($font);
        $font_height = ImageFontHeight($font);

        $text_width = $font_width * strlen($text);
        // Position to align in center
        $position_center = ceil(($width - $text_width) / 2);
         /*
        -----------
        Text Height
        -----------
        */
     $text_height = $font_height;
     // Position to align in abs middle
    $position_middle = ceil(($height - $text_height) / 2);
    ImageString($im, $font,  $position_center, $position_middle, $text, $textcolor);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    // Draw a  line
    if($width < $height)
    {

    imageline($im, 0, 0, 0, $height, $white);   
    }
    else
    {
    imageline($im, 0, 0, $width, 0, $white);
    }
    //return array ($position_center , $position_middle); 
     return $im ;
}
$width = $canvas_inner_width;
$height = 15;
$im = centertext($width , $height, $w);
$sx = imagesx($im);
$sy = imagesy($im);
$marge_right = $canvas_width/2 - $sx/2;
$marge_bottom = 20;
//Merge the im onto our photo with an opacity of 50%
imagecopymerge($canvas, $im, imagesx($canvas) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($canvas) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($im), imagesy($im), 100);
$width = 15;
$height = $canvas_inner_height;
$im_vertical = centertext($width , $height ,$l);

$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = $canvas_width/2 - $sx/2;

$sx = imagesx($im_vertical);
$sy = imagesy($im_vertical);

imagecopymerge($canvas, $im_vertical, imagesx($canvas) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($canvas) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($im_vertical), imagesy($im_vertical), 100);

/* create new image which show product design*/
$canvas_inner = imagecreatetruecolor($canvas_inner_width, $canvas_inner_height);
imagesetthickness($canvas_inner, 5);

$white = imagecolorallocate($canvas_inner,  0, 83, 150);
imagerectangle($canvas_inner, 0, 0, $canvas_inner_width, $canvas_inner_height, $white);
function draw_roundrectangle($img, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $radius, $color,$corner_shape,$corner_val) {
//imagesetthickness($canvas_inner, 2);
if($corner_val[1] !='')
{
$radius=$corner_val[1];
$radius=$radius*4;
switch ($corner_shape[1]) 
{
case "round":

imagesetthickness($img, 3);

  $png_imagec1 = imagecreate($radius, $radius);
                 imagecolorallocate($png_imagec1, 0, 0, 0);
                 imagesetthickness($png_imagec1, 3);
                 $gray_notchc1 = imagecolorallocate($png_imagec1, 0, 83, 150);
                 $bluec1 = imagecolorallocate($png_imagec1, 102, 102, 102);
                 $xc = 0;
                 $yc = 0;
                 $wc = imagesx($png_imagec1) - 1;
                 $zc = imagesy($png_imagec1) - 1;
                 imageline($png_imagec1, $xc, $yc, $xc, $yc+$zc, $bluec1);
                 imageline($png_imagec1, $xc, $yc, $xc+$wc, $yc, $bluec1);
                 imagearc($png_imagec1,$x1+$radius, $y1+$radius, $radius*2, $radius*2, 180 , 270, $gray_notchc1);
                 imagecopymerge($img, $png_imagec1, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($png_imagec1), imagesy($png_imagec1), 100);

break;

default:

}


}


}

$color=imagecolorallocate($canvas_inner, 0, 83, 150);
draw_roundrectangle($canvas_inner,0,0,$canvas_inner_width,$canvas_inner_height,4,$color ,$corner_shape,$corner_val);


$canvas_inner_sx = imagesx($canvas_inner);
$canvas_inner_sy = imagesy($canvas_inner); 
$canvas_sx = imagesx($canvas);
$canvas_sy = imagesy($canvas);
$x_co = ($canvas_sx/2)-($canvas_inner_sx/2);
$y_co = ($canvas_sy/2)-($canvas_inner_sy/2);

imagecopymerge($canvas, $canvas_inner, ceil($x_co), ceil($y_co), 0, 0, imagesx($canvas_inner), imagesy($canvas_inner), 100); 
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

imagejpeg($canvas);
imagedestroy($canvas);
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is a lot of code to look over, perhaps you could narrow down the problem a bit? Are you asking how to [create rounded corners](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2009/05/generate-images-with-round-corners-on.html)?

Comment: yes rounded and chamfer according to user selected radius and shape.You can check this code in any php file.if user will select radius and shape only for top left and right from drop downs then only above shapes will change according to radius.

Comment: I have already checked the same url.Please have a look in my code.

Comment: @php_dev code is working. I just have a question why not do it in css? Isn't it easier?

Comment: I need to create image dyanmically according to user selection.you can see in my code i am creating image dynamically

Comment: dont understand how i can solve this.Every time adding top left shape.I can add the reference website link.